# UK visa refused under Paragraph 9.7.1

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My sister's UK visa application was refused under Paragraph 9.7.1. She forgot she had a visa refused 11 years ago. Can she reapply?

Comment: For those not familiar with UK refusals, paragraph 9.7.1 is a discretionary refusal for submitting false information.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can edit into the question a scan of the refusal letter, with all personal information blacked out.